# sublime shortcut for code folding doesn't work

Tags: sublimetext3

I'm trying to make a code folding shortcut the following ones don't work no matter what i do.... why is that?

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+k"], "command": "toggle_side_bar" },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+w"], "command": "toggle_setting", "args": {"setting": "word_wrap"}},
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+1"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 1} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+2"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 2} },
    { "keys": ["ctrl+alt+3"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 3} }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

On linux those are done with `{ "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+1"], "command": "fold_by_level", "args": {"level": 1} },`. Probably it is the same with windows. 
You can inspect that going to `Preferences ▶ Key Bindings` a search for `fold_by_level` on the file with sublime's default keymap (at left side).

If you don't like those mappings you can use my custom [folding plugin](https://github.com/Corleo/st_settings/blob/master/custom_foldLevel.py) by placing it at your sublime User directory - go to `Preferences ▶ Browse Packages...` and then to User dir. After that you need to add a keymap for this at the right side of `Preferences ▶ Key Bindings`:

```
    {
        "keys": ["ctrl+k", "ctrl+,"],
        "command": "prompt_fold_level"
    },
```

Pressing `"ctrl+k", "ctrl+,"` opens a prompt to type a folding level.

Comment: My goal is to not have to use Ctrl+K. I want to mainly replace that command with a different combo. Like ctrl+f + ctr+1 or something

ideally id like to just do ctrl+1 or ctrl+2 why do i have to do two sequences to call a folder command. that seems silly to me.

Comment: keys 'ctrl+<number>' are already used by sublime to change focus group so that's why you can't use it. The 'ctrl+k' seems to be used by sublime to augment shortcut key namespace. In linux I can use your "ctrl+alt+1" shortkey. Maybe in your system some pluging are already using it.